# RxJS Observable result from an Observable's output

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an Angular 8 application, that uses two layers to store data: `StorageService` abstracts away the actual HTTP service calls, while it itself does not contain other methods than `get` and `save` of various data types.

Other services like `BookmarkService` use `StorageService` and implement the more complex business logic like adding a new bookmarked article.

The catch is, we might have to call `StorageService` twice, to load the data and then to save it.

I would like to expose potential errors to the caller site properly and I am wondering what the best solution would be to implement something like this, without introducing RxJS Subject objects at all. For example, is there any way to achieve this via merely piping? Can someone please give me an example on how to properly implement this pattern?

```
export class BookmarkService {

  constructor(private storageService: StorageService) {}

  addArticleToBookmarks(article: Article): Observable<SaveResponse> {

    this.storageService.getBookmarkedArticles().subscribe(articles =>

      articles.push(article);

      this.storageService.saveBookmarkedArticles(articles).subscribe(saveResponse => ...)

    });

    // want to return an Observable of saveResponse, if getBookmarkedArticles completed, 
    // or the error output of getBookmarkedArticles if it failed
    return ...

  }
```

Comment: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) or [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) (also known as `flatMap`) operator.

Here's a good explanation about the difference between both: https://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2017/03/29/switchmap-vs-flatmap-rxjs/

Example using `switchMap`:

```js
    addArticleToBookmarks(article: Article): Observable<SaveResponse> {
        return this.storageService.getBookmarkedArticles().pipe(
            switchMap(articles => {
                articles.push(article);
                return this.storageService.saveBookmarkedArticles(articles)
            })
        );
    }
```

I have not tested it, but I'm quite sure, this will work

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this ?

```js
addArticleToBookmarks(article: Article): Observable<SaveResponse> {

  this.storageService.getBookmarkedArticles()
  .pipe(
    catchError(err => console.error(err))
    switchMap(articles => {
      articles.push(article);
      return this.storageService.saveBookmarkedArticles(articles);
    }
  ).subscribe(saveResponse => ...)

}
```